# Is it possible to change tail's default line count?

Tags: linux, tail

When I use `tail file`, tail by default prints the last 10 lines.

Is it possible to change that default in the system level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but **you can use alias**.

Add to your `.bashrc` this string:

```
alias tails='tail -n 15'
```

...and run

```
$ source .bashrc
```

now every time you try to type:

```
$ tails file
```

you will get the last 15 lines of `file`

Comment: alternatively, put this in your .bashrc: function tail { /usr/bin/tail -n 15 $* }

Answer (score 10):

No, the default number of lines produced by `tail` (and `head`) is mandated by the POSIX standard:

> [If neither `-c` nor `-n` is specified, `-n 10` shall be assumed.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/tail.html)

To get a different number of lines, use the `-n` command line option, or create a shell function:

```
mytail ()  { tail -n 5 "$@"; }
```

or, if you really want to keep the name of the utility and just change the default number of lines,

```
tail ()  { command tail -n 5 "$@"; }
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this you'd need to modify the source code and recompile it. But it looks like a waste of time and effort. Just use

```
tail -n 42
```

to output the last 42 lines.